Debug.php file not generating in wp-content folder
i can able to connect to ftp/vs code. but our website not loading, so i used below code
We are using below code in wp-config.php file :
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
if (WP_DEBUG) {
 
        @error_reporting(E_ALL);
 
        @ini_set('log_errors', true);
 
        @ini_set('log_errors_max_len', '0');
 
        define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
 
        define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
 
        define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
 
        define('SAVEQUERIES', true);
 
}

Still debug.php file is not generating. how to resolve the issue?

Does it work if you manually create wp-content/debug.log with appropriate permissions for your PHP interpreter to write to it?
